# How to add a picturebox above a button control

Tags: c#

I have a `picturebox1 -> Button -> picturebox2` all three are in a consecutive layer so which I want is that `picturebox2` should be appear within the button when I debug the program.

My code is,

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picturebox2.parent = button;
        picturebox.backcolor = color.transparent;
     }
```

I am using .jpg for `picturebox1` and a .png for `picturebox2` but its not appearing. I mean the picture of `picturebox2` should appear above the button.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Image` and `ImageAlign` properties of Button control? Why do you want to put it in a separate picturebox and make things complex?

Comment: What do you try to accomplish? I agree with @PradeepKumar - seems to me like the image and background image properties of the button would be a better choise.

Comment: sry but i want to know this thing... i know button image will be helpfull but want to know this thing

Comment: You probalby need to nest all 3 controls: `button.Parent = picturebox;`

Comment: have done it b4 but not working - @tah

Comment: do not set button as a parent to picturebox2.. Comment that line

Comment: I dont know why people vote my question negetive if u can give me a real answer then its requested to give me the answer that will be a great help if it seems so easy for him/her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to nest all 3 controls.
- You also need to correct the `Location` of the nested controls or else they keep the original location, which are relative to their original parents, probably to the form, and not to their new parents!!

This should work better:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button.Parent = picturebox;
    picturebox2.Parent = button;
    picturebox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    button.Location = new Point(1,2);      // or whatever you want!!
    picturebox2.Location = new Point(3,4); // or whatever you want!!
 }
```

You may also want to consider simply using the `Image` and/or the  `BackGroundImage` properties of the `Button`..

**Note:** If you want your `Button` to let the bottom `PictureBox` shine through you need to not only set its `Color` but also it's `FlatStyle` to `Flat`!

Comment: thnx but its not working for me i know the code is correct i have tried it before actually i cant get the right location for it

Comment: It works fine here. Explain just how it is not working'. Also: Which pb is the top one? pb2?

Comment: have got it for the button you need to specify the location then u have to add the picturebox location its just a perspective to that button location pictureBox6.Parent = button5;
            button5.Location = new Point(66, 58);  
            
            pictureBox6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3,4);
            pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

Comment: Each loacation is relative to the direct parent only. So setting them all to  (0,0) will place the child at the top left corner.. Also take note of my updated remark about the FlatStyle!

Comment: thnx every1 thaks a lot for supporting me its very helpful for me and a special thanks Taw.

Comment: @arn48 in an answer solved your problem you should mark at as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.